# Get time of message receipt by pubsub topic

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

As a subscriber to a pubsub topic, is it possible for me to find out what time a message was received by pubsub? That is, can a subscriber that has just received a message find out what time the corresponding publisher published the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with a [pull subscriber](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull). Use the [`publishTime` field of `PubsubMessage`](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage).

If you are using a client library, read the library docs on how to access this. For example, with the python client lib, it is accessible via the [`publish_time` field on the `Message` class](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/pubsub/subscriber/api/message.html).